# Linux Mint 19: reset user password from grub bash on a MacBook Pro 2010

Tags: linux, bash, grub, linux-mint, macbook

I'm running Linux Mint 19 on a MacBook Pro 2010 as the sole OS on the machine.
I need to reset my password but the grub menu doesn't show up. I can only access the grub minimal bash shell by keeping the ESC key pressed at boot.

What is the procedure to follow in the grub shell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you enter `normal` and press enter from the grub shell?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:

https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/forgotten-password.html

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.